# C++ Program crash on ApplyTheme method

Tags: c++, com, powerpoint, ole, office-automation

I'm learning C++ PowerPoint automation basing on this sample code

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CppAutomatePowerPoint-024b696c/sourcecode?fileId=52793&pathId=1940694257

Everything looks clear to me, but I've got problem when I'm trying to change default template to my custom template saved on disk. I wrote following line:

```
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pPres, L"ApplyTheme", 1, L"D:\\template.thmx" );
```

which is reproduction of this working line from VBA:

```
Call pptPres.ApplyTheme("D:\template.thmx")
```

The problem is that application is crashing on this line.

**Edit:**

Found the problem (stupid one), but still program crashes after fixing it.

pPres should be type of Presentation, not Presentations (which is collection of Presentation).

The problem now is in this line in AutoWrap function (full code provided in link above)

```
// Make the call 
hr = pDisp->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, 
    autoType, &dp, pvResult, NULL, NULL);
```

After hitting that line I get unhandled exception and app breaks on LeaveCriticalSection in _unlock in mlock.c.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: The program exits with code 0 without any error messages. I don't know if there's any method to obtain error code from that line.

Comment: I've obtained OLE error code: 0x80020006

Comment: With error lookup tool in VS, it means: unknown name.I guess you should pass a name of the built-in template for the function "ApplyTheme", not a file.

Comment: Got same error when tried to apply builtin theme from:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\THEMES12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example you give us, you can not pass the  wchar_t* string as an function parameter which you want to invoke in AutoWrap, you need package it as a BSTR type, which has a different memory layout that that of wchar_t* string, so it will cause crash.

The correct way is in the example you give us:

```
    VARIANT x; 
    x.vt = VT_BSTR; 
    x.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"All-In-One Code Framework"); 
    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pTxtRange, L"Text", 1, x); 
    VariantClear(&x);
```

Comment: Already tried that, same result. Also tried DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT  (Set in VBA) and DISPATCH_METHOD (Call in VBA)

Comment: What is the return type of function "ApplyTheme"? void?

Comment: Fixing my mistake (I used Presentations type instead of Presentation) and passing string as BSTR works perfectly. Thank you